# Modify and add to MySQL result

Tags: php, mysql, sql, json, pdo

How can I add a custom key value pair to the existing SQL result?

```
<?php
    require_once "dbaccess.php";

    $json = array();
    $access = new DatabaseAccess();
    $sql = $access->Connect();
    $stmt = $sql->prepare("select * from people");
    $stmt->execute();
    $result = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);    

    foreach($result as $key => $value){
        $json[$key] = $value;    
    };

    echo json_encode($json, JSON_UNESCAPED_SLASHES);
?>
```

The current JSON result is :

```
[
 {
  "id": "1",
  "first_name": "James",
  "last_name": "Haze"
 },
 {
  "id": "2",
  "first_name": "Neo",
  "last_name": "Anderson"
 }
]
```

How can I add to the current elements `"country": "Australia"` without modifying MySQL database? I want the result to look like this:

```
[
 {
  "id": "1",
  "first_name": "James",
  "last_name": "Haze",
  "Country": "Australia"
 },
 {
  "id": "2",
  "first_name": "Neo",
  "last_name": "Anderson",
  "Country": "Australia"
 }
]
```

Is it possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just select the additional "columns" you want in your SQL:

```
$stmt = $sql->prepare("select
                              id
                            , first_name
                            , last_name
                            , 'Australia' as Country
                         from people");
```

As an aside, you shouldn't use `*` in your select queries - that makes them behave weird when you add new column names and hides errors when you rename a column.

If you want to select a variable value, you can do that by interpolating it into your SQL directly:

```
$stmt = $sql->prepare("select
                              id
                            , first_name
                            , last_name
                            , '$country_name' as Country
                         from people");
```

Even though it is not necessary for country names, it is still a good practice to use (named) SQL placeholders, so you really should be doing it as:

```
$stmt = $sql->prepare("select
                              id
                            , first_name
                            , last_name
                            , :country as Country
                         from people");
$stmt->execute([':country' => $country_name]);
```

(This is mostly when reusing this code elsewhere, as I'm unaware of valid country names that contain single quotes)

Comment: That column doesn't actually exists in the database and modifying the database not an option.

Comment: You don't need to select the column. You can select constants and give them a name.

Comment: Oh ok, instead of hard coding Australia, how can i bring the value from PHP global variable $countryName?

Comment: You should edit your question above and ask that in your question. You can for example interpolate that into your SQL string - I'll update my answer above.

Answer (score 1):

you could add the values you need  directly in select

```
 $stmt = $sql->prepare("select id
                        , firt_name
                        , last_name
                        , 'Australia' AS country
                         from people");
```